# How to find unclosed DataReader?

Tags: c#, datareader

I maintain a large application in ASP.Net 1.1 that has been altered by many people (including students). Obviously, the code has rarely been reviewed, so it is a lot of... err... stupid bugs. The most problematic are the never closed DataReader.
And there are everywhere, up to ten per page. Since this project is about a hundred pages with easily 300+ classes, I just depressed at the thought of finding all the unclosed DataReader.

I know it's hopeless, but is there an easy way to find all these unclosed DataReader? some software or visual studio 2003 tweak...

Comment: I think the only way is to ctr+F `DataReader` and wrap it in `using` statement. If you have ReSharper you can use "Find Usages" to view all DataReaders in one window

Comment: Maybe a custom FxCop rule would work? Strike that - some research suggests that might not be feasible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408546/how-to-validate-datareader-is-actually-closed-using-fxcop-custom-rule

Comment: @Stecya: Yep, but they are buried into two different solutions. And I can't wrap them in `using`, since it's .Net 1.1. I've already put a lot of `try{} catch{} finally{}`, but still not enough :(

Comment: "Phoenix" as mentioned in above thread looks promising: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/04/14/data-flow-analysis-rules-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: Yes, in VS2010. If there is the same in VS2003 for .Net 1.1, I'll rest in peace.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the "correct" way to use a DataReader is either

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = ...) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
SqlDataReader dr = ...
try {
    ...
} finally {
    dr.Close();
}
```

So, the simple solution is just to do a full-project search for `SqlDataReader` and `IDataReader`. If it is

- not inside a using clause or
- not immediately followed by `try`

then it's most likely used incorrectly and needs to be fixed.

Note that the following code:

```
SqlDataReader dr = ...
...
// do something
...
dr.Close();
```

is incorrect, since an exception thrown during `// do something` will leave the DataReader open.

Comment: Totally agree. But this project started 7 years ago, versioned on VSS, still has a lot of bug, and I'm here since last year... I put some `finally` everywhere I can, but I don't have the time to search for all of them by hand.

Comment: Visual Studio can do a find in files, you shouldn't have to find them by hand. Or use `grep` to find them all. Yes, you have to make the modifications by hand but maybe you could enlist some of the students you mentioned to help out :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the replace in files features under Find and Replace. Use Regular expression.

1. Replace `{SqlDataReader.*}$` with `using(\1) \{`.
2. Then replace `using({using(.*)} \{` with `\1`.
3. Compile and go through each error and place only the closing curly braces.

**But make sure you backup your files before you start.**

This way, you can skip those that already have a `using` block to close the data reader.