# How to check if IDataReader is closed by using the .net compiler API

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

I am trying to write a code analyzer that will check if there are any IDataReaders that are not closed.

I have gone through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408546/how-to-validate-datareader-is-actually-closed-using-fxcop-custom-rule) but it does not explain how it can be done, I have also tried to read through the documentation in the [github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/master/docs/Writing%20dataflow%20analysis%20based%20analyzers.md) link The English language used here is too complicated and I did not understand how I will be able to find all instances of type IDataReader and verify that the method close() is being called on it before any variable of the said type goes out of scope.

I have tried creating a project of type Analyzer with code fix in visual studio, I tried to register the operation context in the Initialize method of my class (Which is extended from the type `DiagnosticAnalyzer` as follows:

```
 [DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class DataReaderAnalyzerAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    public const string DiagnosticId = "DataReaderAnalyzer";

    private static readonly LocalizableString Title = new LocalizableResourceString(nameof(Resources.AnalyzerTitle), Resources.ResourceManager, typeof(Resources));
    private static readonly LocalizableString MessageFormat = new LocalizableResourceString(nameof(Resources.AnalyzerMessageFormat), Resources.ResourceManager, typeof(Resources));
    private static readonly LocalizableString Description = new LocalizableResourceString(nameof(Resources.AnalyzerDescription), Resources.ResourceManager, typeof(Resources));
    private const string Category = "DBConnectionCheck";

    private static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Error, isEnabledByDefault: true, description: Description);

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics { get { return ImmutableArray.Create(Rule); } }

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {

        context.RegisterOperationAction((operationContext) => 
        {
            ((Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.AssignmentExpressionSyntax)((Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.ExpressionStatementSyntax)operationContext.Operation.Syntax).Expression).Left
        }
           , OperationKind.ExpressionStatement);
    }
}
```

I want to find all the references of the occurrence of the variable that holds the type IDataReader, make sure that the close method is being called in this variable before it is lost out of scope.

A sample of my code that I would like to analyze is as follows.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IDataReader reader = null;
        try
        {

            Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ApplicationConnection");



            reader = GetDataReader(db);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                   //Do somethig with the data here
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null && !reader.IsClosed)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
public static IDataReader GetDataReader(Database db)
    {
        DbCommand dbcmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand("some select statement to get data from oracle data base");
        var reader = db.ExecuteReader(dbcmd);
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately, the code shown *isn't great*, and IMO it would be the wrong solution to write an analyzer to enforce it.

There is a very simple way of doing this style of operation, and it mostly involves forgetting about `Close`, and using the fact that it is `IDisposable` - which is the intended API for this kind of scenario. Then it becomes much, much simpler - so much simpler that a: you don't need a special analyzer for it, and b: existing analyzers that work against `IDisposable` probably do the job for you.

```cs
using var reader = GetDataReader(db);
while (reader.Read())
{
    //Do somethig with the data here
}
```

with **no** `try`/`catch`/`finally` etc; the compiler will add everything you need for this to do the right thing, simply via the `using`. Note that with older compilers, this needs to be:

```cs
using (var reader = GetDataReader(db))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //Do somethig with the data here
    }
}
```

As a side note: I would strongly suggest *not* fighting the ADO.NET API - it isn't a useful way of spending your time; tools like Dapper do *most common things for you*, so you don't need to write this code - and it knows all the corner cases to avoid.

A typical Dapper usage might be:

```cs
string region = ...
var users = connection.Query<User>(
    "some * from Users where Region = @region",
    new { region } // parameters
).AsList();
```

with the library dealing with all the ADO.NET details internally.

Comment: In my experience, using the `using` statement does not actually close the datareader (I am using Microsoft Enterprise Library, that is communicating with Oracle database) 
 the source code of my web application has several thousands of methods that is returning IDataReader from the DAL layer, refactoring everything is not an option for me, even if the using statement would somehow suddenly start working.

Comment: @VishweshwarKapse with respect, I do not believe you are correct; here's [`DbDataReader`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/System/Data/Common/DbDataReader.cs,66), which all readers *in practice* derive from - note that `Dispose()` calls `Close()` - in fact, that is *all* it does. And here's [OracleDataReader](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/netfxsp/ndp/fx/src/DataOracleClient/System/Data/OracleClient/OracleDataReader@cs/2/OracleDataReader@cs) - it doesn't change `Dispose()`

Comment: @VishweshwarKapse if you're using EntLib and EntLib is doing something funny: frankly - the mistake here is *using EntLib*; that codebase has been abandoned for about a decade, IIRC

Comment: @VishweshwarKapse I've checked the EntLib source; there is a wrapper (`DataReaderWrapper`), but `Dispose()`  still does `if(!innerReader.IsClosed) { innerReader.Dispose(); }` - so it still ultimately *calls `Dispose()`, which calls `Close()`*

Comment: Dear @Marc I would really like my code analyzer to work, because I already have a code  base that is really really big (A massive product which is more than 10 years old) refactoring the entire code is not an option for me, Is there a way in which I can get the code analyzer to work..??

Comment: @VishweshwarKapse yes, analyzers in general work; it is outside of my expertise to comment on problems with them, though

Answer (score 0):

The below code is a non battle hardened approach you can follow.

```cs
analysisContext.RegisterCompilationStartAction(compilationContext =>
{
    var variables = new HashSet<string>();
    var tree = compilationContext.Compilation.SyntaxTrees.First();

    //iterate over all childnodes starting from root
    foreach (var node in tree.GetRoot().ChildNodes())
    {
        var flat = Flatten(node).ToList();
        //find all variable declarations
        var varDecls = flat.OfType<VariableDeclarationSyntax>();
        foreach (var decl in varDecls)
        {
            if (!(decl.Type is IdentifierNameSyntax id)) continue;
            if (!id.Identifier.Text.Equals("IDataReader")) continue;
            //if you are declaring an IDataReader, go store the var name in set
            foreach (var reader in decl.Variables)
            {
                variables.Add(reader.Identifier.Text);
            }
        }
        //find all method calls i.e. reader.Read() etc
        var invokes = flat.OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>();
        foreach (var invoke in invokes)
        {
            var memberAccess = invoke.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;
            var ident = memberAccess.Expression as IdentifierNameSyntax;
            if(!variables.Contains(ident.Identifier.Text)) continue;
            var name = memberAccess.Name as IdentifierNameSyntax;
            //if we find any Close() method on reader, remove from var set
            if (name.Identifier.Text.Equals("Close"))
            {
                variables.Remove(ident.Identifier.Text);
            }
        }
    }
    // if we have any variables left in set it means Close() was never called
    if (variables.Count != 0)
    {
        //this is where you can report
        //var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, location, value);

        //context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
    }
 
});

public static IEnumerable<SyntaxNode> Flatten(SyntaxNode node)
{
    yield return node;
    var childNodes = node.ChildNodes();
    foreach (var child in childNodes)
        foreach (var descendant in Flatten(child))
            yield return descendant;
}
```

Comment: if the source code contains `var reader = GetDataReader(db)` the text IDataReader wont be present in the source code, is there a way to mitigate this issue?

Comment: Will GetDataReader be in the same class?

Comment: No It will be in a different class, The GetDataReader method name is also not fixed, we can have various method names that returns the type IDataReader from a class meant for database query execution, another class uses ths Data access class to call the GetDataReader type of methods

Comment: Another important point to note is that we could have some code like this

`IDataReader dr = null
dr = DAL.GetOrderDetailsDataReader(db, some other paramters)
whilel(dr.Read()) { do something with data }
dr = DAL.GetSomeThingElseDataReader(db, some other parameters)
dr.close();`

this above code is a violation because the close() method is not closed before the first dr goes out of scope